# Get left mouse button status without event

Tags: java, swing

I need to scale my dialogs, when moving them to a different screen. Since scaling all components is quite expensive, I only want to do it once, when the dialog is moved to its new location.

So I used a timer, which restarts with every incoming componentMoved event, to know, when the dialog stops moving. This works great, as long as the mouse is released when stopping the dialog.

If the dialog stops moving and the mouse is still pressed, scaling works. But as soon, as I release the mouse, my L&F engine resizes the dialog to its previous size, which is very inconvenient.

I tried `pack()`, setting the size manually (I know, bad practice), I tried `setVisible(false)` before scaling and `setVisible(true)` afterwards, but as long as the mouse is pressed, my L&F engine resizes the dialog to its previous size.

Sadly, all MouseEvents concerning the titleBar are swallowed by the engine, so I cannot simply use a mouseReleased event to trigger scaling.

This is why I need to find out, if the mouse is still pressed without having to use an event. Is there any way? JNI somehow?

I cannot show an example, because without the L&F Engine, it works fine. Not using it is also not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use `ComponentListener`. When windows size is changed, your layout manager must trigger relayout and component sizes must be changed.

Also for debugging purposes you can use AWTEventListener to get all events which are thrown in your UI.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(...);
```

> > setting the size manually (I know, bad practice)

It's not a bad practice. Especially when you want to restore previous size of your window. `pack()` is simply preferred way.

Comment: I tried previously getting all events with your suggested method. But since the titleBar swallows all events, it didn't resolve the issue. In my understanding, the suggested way to set a dialog size is via a LayoutManager due to crossplatform and different resolution problems. But thank you, for your suggestion

Comment: Use the first proposal (register `ComponentListener`). When you use a `LayoutManager` your components must get ComponentEvent about size change. You can register listener on content pane of your dialog/frame.

Comment: I am using a ComponentListener. Whenever the component has stops moving, the relayout is triggered. The problem is, if I release the mouse AFTER relayout, the L&F engine resizes the dialog to its previous size. It's a bug, but I need to work around it.